# H1 text not showing with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

No matter what I do my h1 tags do not show. I am using bootstrap 4. I do not know why this is happening as I was able to add placeholder text before.

```css
body {
    background-color: #363636;
}

.navbar-nav > .nav-item > a {
    color: #FF20E9;
}

.navbar-nav > .nav-item > a:hover {
    color: #A60F97;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #FD9DFF;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    transition: .25s;
}

.home-text {
    display: block;
    color: beige;
}
```

```html
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-custom navbar-custom fixed-top">
            
            <a class="navbar-brand text-body" href="index.html">Techqueen</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler p-4 bg-custom" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbarcollapse">
                <img src="images/navbar.png" alt="Navbar Toggler" width="30px">
            </button>
            
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbarcollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link p-4" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link p-4" href="#">Images</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section>
        <div class="home-text">
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Since stack overflow wants more details i will give details about my code.

Comment: Works fine. Check if you have a custom CSS which is set to `h1 {display:none}`

Comment: no my css does not have that now it just flashes on screen for 1 second then disappears

Comment: That's definitely custom CSS. Look closely.

Comment: wdym custom css i put my css btw?

Comment: Look at your `style.css` file. find `h1 {display:none}` OR open the chrome dev tools and see why h1 goes to display:none after 1 second.

Comment: i dont have ```h1 {display:none}``` in my file and btw which browser or thing are you using to run the code?

Comment: Have you tried on a browser without any extensions/plugins ?

Comment: [This browser](https://jsfiddle.net/x9b470y3/)

Comment: its definitely not my browser as I just looked at the code on edge and firefox

Comment: It's appear, but behind the navbar.

Comment: no it doesnt for me

Answer (score 0):

The `<nav>` has `position: fixed;`, so it's "over" your title.
You need to "push" the `<h1>` below the `<nav>`.

Try adding :

```
body {
    padding-top: 88px;
}
```

Comment: thx it worked guess the navbar was hiding my home text

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello**, I tried your code and I check the inspect element and I saw your h1 was in the back of the navbar so if you want it to be seen you have to add this code in your CSS:

```
.home-text {
    padding-top: 88px;
    display: block;
    color: beige !important;
}
```

or like the other guy did. But the other guy did was much better so that you dont need to put the padding on many classes. so just put the padding on the body like this:

```
body {
    padding-top: 88px;
}
```

Good Luck Hope I Helped. Let me Know if I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Position: fixed takes the element out of normal document flow. This means your h1 is appearing under it. By removing fixed-top from the nav, you can see it is still there. I would recommend using position: sticky instead to avoid this problem.

```css
body {
    background-color: #363636;
}

.navbar-nav > .nav-item > a {
    color: #FF20E9;
}

.navbar-nav > .nav-item > a:hover {
    color: #A60F97;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #FD9DFF;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    transition: .25s;
}

.home-text {
    display: block;
    color: beige;
    
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-custom navbar-custom">
            
            <a class="navbar-brand text-body" href="index.html">Techqueen</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler p-4 bg-custom" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbarcollapse">
                <img src="images/navbar.png" alt="Navbar Toggler" width="30px">
            </button>
            
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbarcollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link p-4" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link p-4" href="#">Images</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section>
        <div class="home-text">
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```